# Поиск в ширину на графе, не вижу логическую ошибку. C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, поиск, графы

Пытаюсь реализовать поиск в ширину на графе. Не вижу логической ошибки, вроде все компилится, но получается не то что я жду.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class lr1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 9;
        int[,] g = new int[,]
        {
           //1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
            {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        };
        print_arr(g, n);
        Console.WriteLine("Введите начальную вершину:");
        int start = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите конечную вершину:");
        int end = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        List<int> open = new List<int>();
        List<int> closed = new List<int>();
        open.Add(start);
        int x;
        while(open.Count > 0)
        {
            x = open[0];
            if(x == end)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вершина найдена");
            }
            closed.Add(open[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("closed");
            print_list(closed);
            open.RemoveAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                    if (g[x, i] == 1)
                    {
                        open.Add(i);
                    }

            }

        }
        print_list(open);
    }
    public static void print_list(List<int> list)
    {
        string s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            s += list[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("List: " + s);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: На данный момент, цель - вывести правильный список open.

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: я проверяю правильность выводя в цикле при каждой итерации список open, и, на данный момент он не правильный. здесь я убрала строчки, где выводился список.

Comment: Вообще-то нужен не список, closed, а булево поле для каждой вершины. Тогда вообще будет просто проверять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    if (g[x, i] == 1)
                    {
                        open.Add(i);
                    }
```

Вот тут вы добавляете вершины, смежные с текущей. Но надо еще сделать проверку, что вершина не находится в closed. Иначе будет зацикливаться, как и происходит.

Пусть closed будет листом булевых значений. Тогда проверка будет проходить так

```
                    if (g[x, i] == 1 && closed[i]==false)
                    {
                        open.Add(i);
                    }
```